# Restore original document id from lda object

Tags: r, lda, tidytext, topicmodels

I'm trying to compare the "consensus" topic prediction (beta) from terms (in a given document) against the most likely predicted topic from the document itself (gamma) using functions from `topicmodels`.
While it's easy to extract the most likely predicted topic from the document using `groupby()` over document and selecting `top_n()` on gamma, but in the "beta" estimate, the unique document id will be suppressed in the output, the output only contains three columns (`topic`, `term`, `beta`). This does not allow one to obtain the "consensus" topic prediction (beta) from terms for a given document.

Using my own data as an example:

```css
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")  # reset to simplified Chinese encoding as the text data is in Chinese
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)

sample_dtm <- readRDS(gzcon(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/gznqlncd9psx3wz/sample_dtm.rds?dl=1")))

lda_out <- LDA(sample_dtm, k = 2, control = list(seed = 1234))

word_topics <- tidy(lda_out, matrix = "beta")

head(word_topics, n = 4)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  topic term      beta
  <int> <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 费解  8.49e- 4
2     2 费解  1.15e- 9
3     1 上    2.92e- 3

document_gamma <- tidy(lda_out, matrix = "gamma")

head(document_gamma, n = 4)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  document topic   gamma
  <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
1 1203232      1 0.00374
2 529660       1 0.0329 
3 738921       1 0.00138
4 963374       1 0.302
```

Is there anyway I can restore the document id from the `lda` output and combine with the `beta` estimate (`word_topics`, which is stored as a `data.frame` object)? Such that it will be much easier to compare the estimated topic from the consensus of `beta` versus that of `gamma`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, I believe the function you want is [`augment()`](https://juliasilge.github.io/tidytext/reference/lda_tidiers.html), which returns a table with one row per original document-term pair, connected to topics.

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")  # reset to simplified Chinese encoding as the text data is in Chinese
#> Warning in Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Chinese"): OS reports request to set
#> locale to "Chinese" cannot be honored
#> [1] ""
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
#> If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
#> library(plyr); library(dplyr)
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
#>     summarize
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)

sample_dtm <- readRDS(gzcon(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/gznqlncd9psx3wz/sample_dtm.rds?dl=1")))

lda_out <- LDA(sample_dtm, k = 2, control = list(seed = 1234))

augment(lda_out, sample_dtm)
#> # A tibble: 18,676 x 4
#>    document term     count .topic
#>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 649      作揖         1      1
#>  2 649      拳头         1      1
#>  3 649      赞           1      1
#>  4 656      住           1      1
#>  5 656      小区         1      1
#>  6 656      没           1      1
#>  7 656      注意         2      1
#>  8 1916     中国         1      1
#>  9 1916     中国台湾     1      1
#> 10 1916     反对         1      1
#> # … with 18,666 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This connects the document ID from the LDA model to the topics. It sounds like you already understand this, but just to reiterate:

- the `beta` matrix is word-topic probabilities
- the `gamma` matrix is document-topic probabilities

Comment: Wow, much thanks to @Julia for clarifying this, it's much straightforward than I thought. (Sorry I didn't notice your response earlier)